# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'infoWindow' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to merge some code from an old map into a new map and I am getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'infoWindow' of undefined" referring to this line

```
polygon.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: html});
```

From this snippet below. I have infoWindow defined at the top of the script but, for brevity didn't include it.

```
geoXml.parseKmlString("<Placemark><name>"+name+"</name>"+kml+"</Placemark>");
       var html = "<strong>" + event + "</strong><br>Issued For: " + area + "<br>Expires: " +dtstring;
       var polygon = geoXml.docs[0].gpolygons[0];
       polygon.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: html});

       google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'mouseover', function(e) {
             var latLng = e.latLng;
                 this.setOptions({fillOpacity:0.80});
                 polygon.infoWindow.setPosition(latLng);
                 polygon.infoWindow.open(map);
        });
```

Comment: If you console.log `polygon` immediately after it is declared, what do you get?

Comment: @sideroxylon thanks for the response. I am not sure exactly what you're asking. I gathered the information which I posted in my OP from the console. If there is something further then I am not sure what you're asking me to do but you can take a look at the test map http://stream.dfwstormforce.com/test/map.html

Comment: If you add (after line 521 in your code) `console.log(polygon)`, what do you get in the console?

Comment: @sideroxylon I get back quite a bit of information but, I am not sure what I am looking for.

Comment: In that case (and seeing as the mouseover function seems to work)  you might have a timing issue, and line 522 is being run before `polygon` has been declared. Maybe try setting a timeout, just to see if that prevents the error.

Comment: I wouldn't exactly say the mouseover function works. While it appears to work it doesn't work like it should. If you notice when the map loads the polys are light. You mousover them they fill in darker which they should load in darker anyways. Then when you mouseover they get even darker to know you're over it but then return to their normal opacity when you move the mouse. So something is weird going on with them. Not sure if this is part of the problem or not. I tried adding a time out of 3-5-10 seconds and still the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [my example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/mesquiteweather_net_PolygonInfoWindowsE_GViz.html?filename=../mesquiteweather_net_nat_warnings.xml) (looks like where your code came from), you would have seen the same error (I have fixed that example).  It happens when the entry in the FusionTable returned by the query doesn't contain a polygon.  The entry in my example is:

> event:Special Weather Statement, expires:2013-05-02T18:00:00-06:00

You can defensively code to not create the infowindow if there isn't a polygon:

```
 var polygon = geoXml.docs[0].gpolygons[0];
 if (polygon) {
   polygon.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: html});
   google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'mouseover', function(e) {
     var latLng = e.latLng;
     this.setOptions({fillOpacity:0.80});
     polygon.infoWindow.setPosition(latLng);
     polygon.infoWindow.open(map);
   });
   google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'mouseout', function() {
     this.setOptions({fillOpacity:0.35});
     polygon.infoWindow.close();
   });
 } else console.log("event:"+event+", expires:"+expires);
```

Comment: BINGO! That did it and yes, that was some of your amazing code there you helped me with a few years back. You my friend are a Googles Map God!